# TailwindCSS Active Link Text Color Not Changing

Tags: javascript, html, css, next.js, tailwind-css

I am using NextJS and Tailwind css to desig a top navigation bar. I want the text color to change for active link. Below is my code:

```js
const Header = () => {
    return(
        <header>
            <nav className="sd:max-w-6xl mx-auto">
                <ul className="flex py-2">
                    <li className="mr-auto ml-4">
                        <Link href="/"><a><Image width={80} height={80} src="/images/brand-logo.png" alt="ECT Logo"/></a></Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className="mr-4 my-auto hover:text-indigo-600 font-normal font-serif text-brand-darkblue text-xl active:text-indigo-600">
                        <Link href="/"><a>Home</a></Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className="mr-4 my-auto hover:text-indigo-600 font-normal font-serif text-brand-darkblue text-xl active:text-indigo-600">
                        <Link href="/user/signup"><a>Join</a></Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className="mr-4 my-auto hover:text-indigo-600 font-normal font-serif text-brand-darkblue text-xl active:text-indigo-600">
                        <Link href="/user/login"><a>Login</a></Link>
                    </li> 
                </ul>
        </nav>
        </header>
    )

}
```

I have also added the following in my tailwind.config.css:

```js
module.exports = {
  #
  variants: {
    extend: {
      textColor: ['active'],
    },
 
}
```

Despite that the Text color doesn't change for active link.

Can you please guide what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems there's a mix-up between two concepts:

1. The `active` state in Tailwind CSS, which refers to the state of an element while it's being pressed (https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#active).
2. The "active" page, indicating the current page's path matches the `nav` item's `href`.

You cannot achieve 2 with 1, they are different things.

To distinguish and indicate the current page (concept 2), you need to compare the current path with the `<Link>` element's path and apply conditional Tailwind classes accordingly.

**For Next.js Pages Router:**

```js
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export const Header = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <header>
      <Link href="/">
        <a className={router.pathname === "/" ? "active" : ""}>
           Home
        </a>
      </Link>
    </header>
  )
}
```

*Source: https://dev.to/yuridevat/how-to-add-styling-to-an-active-link-in-nextjs-593e*

**For Next.js App Router (Update March 2024):**

```
'use client';
 
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation';
 
export const Header = () => {
  const pathname = usePathname();

  return (
    <header>
      <Link href="/">
        <a className={pathname === "/" ? "active" : ""}>
           Home
        </a>
      </Link>
    </header>
  );
};
```

I like to do something like this:

```
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";

const NAV_ITEMS = [
  { href: "/", label: "Home" },
  { href: "/about", label: "About" },
];

export const Nav = () => {
  const pathname = usePathname();

  return (
    <nav>
      {NAV_ITEMS.map(({ href, label }) => {
        const isActive = pathname === href;

        return (
          <Link
            key={href}
            href={href}
            className={`${isActive ? "text-blue-500" : "text-black"} text-sm`}
          >
            {label}
          </Link>
        );
      })}
    </nav>
  );
};
```

With a helper library like [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames), this would become:

```
<Link
  key={href}
  href={href}
  className={classnames("text-sm", {
    "text-blue-500": isActive,
    "text-black": !isActive,
  })}
>
  {label}
</Link>;
```

Applying this to your code, you could adjust the `className` like so:

```js
<Link href="/user/signup">
    <a className={`mr-4 my-auto hover:text-indigo-600 font-normal font-serif text-xl ${router.pathname == "/user/signup" ? "text-indigo-600" : "text-brand-darkblue"}`}>
        Home
    </a>
</Link>
```

Comment: Thank you. It solved and problem and also clarified my concepts. A few points could be useful for others who are in similar situation.

In the code, it should be const router = useRouter(); // Not userRouter
Also, I put the class element in the <li> tag it also worked.

Thank you once again.

Comment: perfect solution, worked for me as well, just want to add that if using the App Router instead of the Pages Router, you wanna import usePathname from next/navigation and not router from next/router, otherwise you'll get NextRouter not mounted errors.

Comment: @xXnikosXx: Thanks, just updated my answer to include info about the app router.

Answer (score 7):

When using NavLink it's add class active to link but not [active state in tailwindcss](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#active)

The simplest way is to use custom variant like this

```
<NavLink to={``}  className={'[&.active]:text-indigo-500}>
</NavLink>
```

This way is both pure css and takes advantage of the power of tailwindcss. Furthermore, avoid using state when it is not necessary to avoid the rendering problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to use NavLink instead of Link it will match the current URL here is an example I've used :

```
<NavLink to={`/${link.name}`}  className={ ({isActive})=>  (" capitalize my-2 flex flex-col ") + (isActive?ActiveLink:NormalLink) }>
              {link.name}
  </NavLink>
```

Comment: Next.js provides a [built-in router](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router) and [`Link`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link) component, it doesn't use `react-router-dom`.

Answer (score 0):

**Using NextJs and Tailwind using toggle dark/light mode, this is how I solved it**

```
    //ActiveLink.js
        import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
        import Link from 'next/link';
        import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
        import { useTheme } from 'next-themes';
        
        
        const ActiveLink = ({ href, children, ...rest }) => {
            const router = useRouter();
            const { theme, systemTheme } = useTheme();
            const useLoaded = () => {
               const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
               useEffect(() => setLoaded(true), []);
               return loaded;
            };
            const mounted = useLoaded();
        
            const isActive = router.asPath === href;
    const currentTheme =
            mounted && theme !== undefined && theme === 'system' ? systemTheme : theme;
        
            const activeLinkBgColor =
                currentTheme === 'dark'
                    ? 'bg-gray-700 text-white'
                    : 'bg-blue-600 text-white';
        
            const themeBgHover =
                currentTheme === 'dark'
                    ? 'hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white'
                    : 'hover:bg-blue-600 hover:text-white ';
        
            const activeLinkAndNotActiveColor = isActive
                ? activeLinkBgColor
                : `text-gray-300 ${themeBgHover}`;
        
            const className = `${activeLinkAndNotActiveColor} px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium`;
        
            return (
                <Link href={href} passHref {...rest}>
                    <a className={className} aria-current={isActive ? 'page' : undefined}>
                        {children}
                    </a>
                </Link>
            );
        };
        
        ActiveLink.propTypes = {
            href: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        };   
        
        
        export default ActiveLink;

// How to use it
 <ActiveLink href='/about'> About </ActiveLink>
```

Result:
[image]
[image]

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to expand the Tailwind modifier to forget about this problem once and for all.

1. Import `tailwindcss/plugin`.
2. Extend standard modifier via plugin.
3. Use `active:text-purple-500`.

```js
// tailwind.config.js
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin');


module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
      // ... some plugins,
      plugin(function({ addVariant }) {
        addVariant('active', ['&:active', '&.router-link-active'])
      })
  ],
}
```

```js
<template>
  <NuxtLink
    class="active:text-purple-500"
  >
    <slot></slot>
  </NuxtLink>
</template>
```

This approach will help:

1. Avoid errors when extending the codebase, since you don't have to remember about the customization of the active state.
2. Migrate components from one project to another.